# function pointers returned by functions

Tags: function, pointers, c++11

I'm trying to learn pointers in C++, but seems that it get more complicated...

In the main loop

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    if (fun == arrfun[i]) break;
}
```

How is that fun==arrfun[i] at fun2 if both fun and arrfun start looping form 0? Hence they should equal at log(x) instead. How could I loop to sin or cos, etc?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef double(*FUNDtoD)(double);
typedef FUNDtoD ARRFUN[];

FUNDtoD funmax(ARRFUN, double);

double fun0(double x) { return log(x); }
double fun1(double x) { return x*x;    }
double fun2(double x) { return exp(x); }
double fun3(double x) { return sin(x); }
double fun4(double x) { return cos(x); }

int main() {

    ARRFUN arrfun = { fun0, fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4 };

    FUNDtoD fun = funmax(arrfun, 1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        if (fun == arrfun[i]) break;
    }

    cout.precision(14);
    cout << "Largest value at x=1 assumed by function # "
        << i << ".\nThe value is " << fun(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}

FUNDtoD funmax(ARRFUN f, double x){
    double m = f[0](x), z;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        if ((z = f[i](x)) > m) {
            m = z;
            k = i;

        }
    }
    return f[k];
}
```

I don't understand how function `FUNDtoD funmax` is working at the bottom, could somebody clarify it please, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that fun==arrfun[i] at fun2 if both fun and arrfun start looping form 0?  > Hence they should equal at log(x) instead. How could I loop to sin or cos, etc?

fun is not being looped, the same pointer is checked against each function pointer stored in the array (arrfun).  It is simply trying to find the index of the returned function pointer.  If sin(x) gave the highest value then that loop would finish with a 4 in i.

> don't understand how function FUNDtoD funmax is working at the bottom, could 
>   somebody clarify it please, many thanks.

It breaks down as follows:

Firstly it performs m = f0;

f[0] -> fun0 so the result is m = log( x );

Next it steps through the other 4 functions and tests whether the operation on x results in a higher valuer than the previous.  It then stores the index of the function that returned the highest value.

Finally it returns that function pointer.